# ScenePhase with @AsyncOpen/@AutoOpen causes reload

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, realm

How do I utilize both `@Environment(\.scenePhase) var phase` and `@AsyncOpen` without causing re-draws on re-open (SwiftUI, Realm SDK)?

Current behavior:
`@AsyncOpen` refreshes each time I close and re-open the app, causing a loading indicator to show each time.

Expected behavior:
The app should re-open from where the user left it.

IMPORTANT - the issue does not exist if I remove `@Environment(\.scenePhase) var phase`

Here's my code:

```
@main
struct RealmMainActorPOCApp: SwiftUI.App {
@Environment(\.scenePhase) var phase
@StateObject var manager = Session.shared

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        Group {
            if let config = manager.configuration {
                OpenSyncedRealmView()
                    .environment(\.realmConfiguration, config)
            } else {
                Login()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
struct OpenSyncedRealmView: View {

@AsyncOpen(appId: "app_name", timeout: 4000) var asyncOpen

var body: some View {
    switch asyncOpen {
    case .open(let realm):
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.realm, realm)
    case .connecting:
        Text("waiting")
    case .error(let err):
        Text("error" + err.localizedDescription)
    case .progress:
        Text("progress")
    case .waitingForUser:
        Text("waiting for user")
    }
}
```

}